# Wordpress functions.php Conditional Tag for Portfolio Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am using Wordpress and Avada theme to build a website. I needed to change logo in some pages so I used some css code in those pages to remove the logo (because avada does not provide this option) and then I inserted the following line of code in order to insert the new one and everything works fine (here is just for a single page with `ID=11`).

```php
add_action( 'avada_logo_prepend', 'logo_image_home' );
function logo_image_home() {
    if( is_page( '11' )  )  {
        echo '<a href=" here I put my href "><img class="lazyload" src="  here I put the link of my logo " data-orig-src=" same here " /></a>';
    }
}
```

the problem is when I try to do the same thing with some portfolio pages (Portfolio posts). I tried to use `if ( is_post_type_archive( '146' ) )` or `if ( is_archive( '146' ) )` instead of `if ( is_page( '146' ) )` but nothing seems work. I am not a developer so this looks quite complicated to me to solve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If anybody has the same problem “is_single( int|string|array $post = ” )” works fine for any post type, except attachments and pages

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has the same problem “is_single( int|string|array $post = ” )” works fine for any post type, except attachments and pages